# Can you use Bitwarden in the cloud but still have a self-hosted backup

Tags: backup, password-management, self-hosting

I understand that Bitwarden can be used completely offline by self-hosting. But self-hosting has its "cons". At least for people who are not technologically inclined. But it also has its pros. Mainly the ability to still access your passwords, if anything happens to Bitwarden servers.

So my question is: Assuming I'm using Bitwarden's online password hosting (the free plan), is there then an option to also self-host offline so that if anything happened to Bitwarden's servers, I'd still have full access to all my passwords?

I'm just asking for a contingency plan. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is No. At this moment they do not support on-prem synchronization with cloud services. While this is not possible, you can however do this manually with import/export features.

This could be done automatically with a cronjob on your on-prem server.

Comment: So if I MANUALLY export my Bitwarden vault, assuming I do it periodically (since I don't know how to use cron-jobs), I'd be a-okay even if the whole Bitwarden server went down permanently, correct?

Comment: Absolutely, you will (i assume you use on-prem as main) always have the latest locally, and can update to the cloud when ever you feel like.

Comment: Thank you for the help Ole.

Comment: You are most welcome, in bitwarden documentation, you can read about backups and restores both for on-prem and cloud. Those details can be used in conjunction with their API and with some read up on crontab you will get very far (and feel quite good about it afterwards).